# what is the code for vb.net window startup?

Tags: windows, vb.net

I have made a program with vb.net and I want that program to run when the windows start up.
I don't know the code.
I want that program to add the window startup when he/she install the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to registry with the following code

```
 My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).SetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath)
    End Sub
```

you can remove it using

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).DeleteValue(Application.ProductName)
```

The above code will add it to all users. You can add it to current user in the following key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Comment: You won't be able to add it for all users unless you're running as Administrator. And not only should you not be doing that as a developer, you can virtually guarantee that your app's *users* will not be running as admin.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a shortcut for the program to Start -> All Programs -> Startup.

Or add an entry to the "Run" key in the registry - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx for more details.

Comment: i want it to add it when he/she install the program.

Comment: Then in your installer just add the value to the Run key in the registry.  The MSDN link I posted is part of the documentation for configuring installers.